# is there any other human with non white / transparent ki in Dragon Ball aside Roshi's lilac ki?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball, dragon-ball-movies

In the advance of the new chapter of Dragon Ball Super , Roshi appears with lilac ki, perhaps the sign of a new technique or transformation. My question is, is there any other human in the Dragon Ball universe who has a non white/transparent ki/aura?

[image]

Comment: I think that the colour only indicates that master roshi is under an evil influence/transformation (maybe something will change in super but i doubt). Purple is usually one of the used colours for such an "evil" entity. Regarding humans i think they were only showed using a white aura

Comment: @proxy I just remembered Bulma and Chichi's auras. Chichi's red "kaioken" aura, though those appeared in humorous scenes, I dont know if they count as "ki"

Comment: Just remembered another one, Krilin's yellow ki, but that probably was an animation mistake since he was along Trunks and Goten super saiyans

Comment: as you have said, for chichi and bulma its just a gag scene there is no reason for them to have ki auras, especially bulma who has never trained any martial arts.